# Python Nested List Comprehensions on Multiple Lists

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I am trying to learn list comprehensions and I have created this trivial example in which I wish to print the strings in list `a` which contain either the words `fox` or `rabbit` while excluding those which contain `red` or `blue`. As it stands, my example works but I want to know if it can be condensed into a single comprehension, thus negating the need for set operations.

```
a = ["the red fox", "the blue fox", "the green fox", 
     "the yellow fox", "the red rabbit", "the yellow rabbit"]
b = ["fox", "rabbit"]
c = ["red", "blue"]

d = set([e for e in a for f in b if f in e]) - set([e for e in a for f in c if f in e])

for d in d:
    print d
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your list comprehension would look like this:

```
d = [x for x in a if any(y in x for y in b) and not any(y in x for y in c)]
```

Note how it almost reads like your specification.

The result is

```
['the green fox', 'the yellow fox', 'the yellow rabbit']
```

Since your sample code used the plain old `in` check, I'm assuming you are looking for substrings here, and "blue" should be considered to be in "the blueish color". Otherwise, split all your strings in `a` by whitespace and rejoin them after calculating your result.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively if you really want to use sets you can do this:

```
[x for x in a if set(x.split() + b) and set(c).isdisjoint(x.split())]
```